# How can I bring php into my html files and where do i store the php files?

Tags: php, html, expression-web

I am very new to web-development and I apologize for a question that may appear silly.

I am using expression web to create most of the cosmetics of my website and I am using php for the coding. I already have resources and have learned about php but i"m new to implementing it. I want to be able to have specific parts of my site generated by php code. For example, the login box and the user profiles. How do I make my html files use those files to generate content and where do I put the php files that the html page will use? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That comment really doesn't help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier way is to have a separate PHP file for everything you want like: loginBox.inc.php, header.php, etc. Then change your html page to php (just the extension), then wherever you want to add the login box, just do:

```
<?php include ('loginBox.inc.php') ?>
```

And all php code from that file will be include. I think this is what you want. For better code maintaing, put all those files in a folder called **includes** or something similar to organize files in a better way.

Comment: Thank you! Can any person access all the php files though? Is there any way to store them so someone cannot open them by themself? Or is this a silly issue I'm worrying about?

Comment: If it worked for you select it as the answer :) No, this will make the webserver to incluide and execute the php code, so clients will see only generated HTML. So, they won't see any php code.

Comment: If I save the php in another folder than the hemp file, how do I tell rhetorically html its location?

Comment: The same way you would any file you're including in an html file such as an image or css file, using relative paths (or you could use explicit paths) So let's say you have a folder called php_includes in your main root folder, you could include the loginBox.inc.php (btw the .inc is not really necessary) by having it point to <?php include('/php_includes/loginBox.inc.php'); ?>